# Intermittent Null reference error Sitecore 8.0 update 6

Tags: content-testing

I am currently facing intermittent null reference error related to content testing pipeline. When I refresh the page Sitecore doesn't throw any error.
After sometime when I click on any content item, I'm facing the below issue.

[image]

[image]

**Update 1** :- Stack trace

> 8596 06:14:53 ERROR Application error.
>   Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   Source: System.Web
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at ASP.sitecore_service_nolayout_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\81e6daec\c5a03d8d\App_Web_fbypcovb.3.cs:line 0
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.ContentTesting    at
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.RenderLayout.EvaluateTestExposure.Process(RenderLayoutArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Layouts.PageContext.BuildControlTree(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)    at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Include the stack trace as quoted text, please. For the search engines. In general though, "why isn't this working?" is very poor for this format.

Comment: @MarkCassidy updated my question by providing logs from the sitecore.

Comment: It looks like you left a (rendering?) parameter somewhere empty... It's impossible to say without any detail about your setup.